Prove that $ \int_{\Omega} \Vert \nabla u\Vert^2 -6F(u)dx=-\int_{\partial \Omega} \Vert \nabla u\Vert^2 x\cdot \vec{n}d\sigma$
Let $\Omega\in \mathbb{R}^3$ be a compact region, $f \in C(\mathbb{R})$ and $F(r)=\int_{0}^{r}f(t) dt$. If $u\in C^2(\Omega)$ satisfies $\Delta u(x)+f(u(x))=0,x\in \Omega$ and $u(x)=0,x\in \partial \Omega$, prove that $$ \int_{\Omega} \Vert \nabla u\Vert^2 -6F(u)dx=-\int_{\partial \Omega} \Vert \nabla u\Vert^2 x\cdot \vec{n}d\sigma,$$
where $\vec{n}$ is the unit normal vector of $\partial \Omega$.
My attempt:
I guess that Green's formula is useful: $$ \int_{\Omega} \nabla f \cdot \nabla g+g \Delta fdx=\int_{\partial \Omega} g\nabla f\cdot \vec{n}d\sigma.$$
(The $f$ in this formula is irrelavant to the $f$ in the above problem.) Let $f=\Vert x\Vert^2,g=F(u)$, then $$\int_{\Omega}f(u)\nabla u \cdot 2x+6F(u)dx=\int_{\partial \Omega}F(u)2x\cdot \vec{n}d\sigma.$$
Let $f=g=u$, then $$\int_{\Omega}\Vert\nabla u \Vert^2+u\Delta udx=0.$$
However, it seems that I can't deduce the required equation from these. Can anyone help me?

Couldnt find a proof of Pohozaev's identity anywhere on the site so I posted it here.

This is the Pohozaev identity: If $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ is an open, bounded set with $C^1$ boundary and $u\in C^2(\Omega) \cap C^1(\overline \Omega)$ satisfies $$\begin{cases}
-\Delta u =f(u), &\text{in } \Omega \\
u=0, &\text{on }\partial \Omega
\end{cases} $$ then $$(2-n)\int_\Omega u f(u) \, dx +2n \int_\Omega F(u) \, dx = \int_{\partial \Omega}(\partial_\nu u)^2(x\cdot \nu) \,d\mathcal H^{n-1}. $$
In your particular case, $n=3$, so $$ -\int_\Omega u f(u) \, dx +6 \int_\Omega F(u) \, dx = \int_{\partial \Omega}(\partial_\nu u)^2(x\cdot \nu) \,d\mathcal H^{n-1}.$$ Moreover, $$-\int_\Omega u f(u) \, dx= \int_\Omega u \Delta u  \, dx= - \int_\Omega \vert \nabla u \vert^2 \, dx $$ and $$\int_{\partial \Omega}(\partial_\nu u)^2(x\cdot \nu) \,d\mathcal H^{n-1}= \int_{\partial \Omega}\vert \nabla u \vert^2(x\cdot \nu) \,d\mathcal H^{n-1} $$ since $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ implies that $\nabla u = (\partial_\nu u ) \nu$ on $\partial \Omega$.
A proof of the Pohozaev identity can be found in Theorem 2.1.8 in Elliptic partial differential equations from an elementary viewpoint by Dipierro and Valdinoci (freely avaliable on ArXiv). If you want to try prove the result for yourself, consider using integration by parts on $$ \int_\Omega \Delta u ( \nabla u \cdot x) \, dx.$$

I am still working on the proof, but I just wanted to create a quick example to demonstrate to myself that the formula is actually true (it is). If you let
$\Omega=\mathbb B(0,1)$ ,  $f=6$, and $u(x)=1-|x|^2$, you will find that $u$ satisfies the BVP
$$\begin{cases}\Delta u+f(u)=0 & \text{in}~\Omega \\ u=0 & \text{on}~\partial\Omega\end{cases}$$
You can also calculate $\nabla u(x)=-2x$, $F(z)=6z$, and $n(x)=x$. That means that the left hand side is
$$\int_\Omega |\nabla u(x)|^2-6F(u(x))~\mathrm d^3x=\int_{\mathbb B(0,1)}\big(40|x|^2-36\big)~\mathrm d^3x \\ =-36\cdot \frac{4\pi}{3}+40\int_0^1\int_{\partial \mathbb B(0,r)}r^2~\mathrm d^2 x~\mathrm dr \\ =-48\pi+40\int_0^1 4\pi r^4~\mathrm dr \\ =-48\pi+40\cdot \frac{4\pi }{5}=-16\pi$$
And the right hand side is
$$-\int_{\partial\Omega}|\nabla u(x)|^2x\cdot n(x)~\mathrm d^2 x=-\int_{\partial\mathbb B(0,1)}|2x|^2~x\cdot x~\mathrm d^2x \\ =-4\int_{\partial \mathbb B(0,1)}|x|^2 \mathrm d^2 x =-4\int_{\partial \mathbb B(0,1)}1~ \mathrm d^2 x  \\ =-16\pi$$
So the formula appears to be true.
